# In R how can you tell if a string includes escape sequences?

Tags: r, escaping

I have a string in R, e.g. x <- "c:\tmp\rest.zip".  How can I detect that it has escape sequences in it, vis. \t and \r?  Us DOS/Windows guys have a habit of using backslashes that R doesn't like and I'm writing a function where I would like to be able to protect the user from themselves.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doubling of the back-slashes in the grep pattern is the path to success:

```
 xtxt <- c("test\n", "of\t", "escapes")
 grep("\\n|\\t", xtxt)
# [1] 1 2
```

Another way to be to search for control characters:

```
 grep("[[:cntrl:]]", xtxt)
#[1] 1 2
```

Comment: doubling worked ok with the logical or but just searching for one of them required a single backslash.  And that also works with the or.  How did you find out that cntrl syntax?

Comment: The help page that has predfined classes like [:cntrl:] is ?regex